# Push on an array when listening to an event

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

I am working with Ionic and I want to push an array of an object, when an event is emitted.

I have this

```
    export  class PublicationService {

    constructor(
        private storage: Storage
    ){}

    private addPublicationSubject = new BehaviorSubject<PublicationModel>(new PublicationModel());
    data = this.addPublicationSubject.asObservable();

    publishData(data: PublicationModel) {
        this.addPublicationSubject.next(data);
    }
   }
```

Here, event is emitted

```
    savePublication() {
    this.newPublication.id_pub = 1;
    this.newPublication.textPub = this.f.text.value;
    this.newPublication.user_sender = 'Juance';
    this.newPublication.datetime = "asd";
    this.pubService.publishData(this.newPublication);
  }
```

And on my home page the event is listen (in ngOnInit)

```
// Variable defined in the component
publications: PublicationModel[] = [];

//ngOnInit
this.pubService.data.subscribe((data) => {
      if (data != null) {
        console.log(data);

        this.publications.push(data);
      }
});
```

Now my problem is: when I try to push the data into the array it tells me it cannot read property of null (this.publications).

When entering the subscribe of the event, it does not take the variable as defined in the component. Any ideas?

[image]

EDIT:

My component HomePage

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss']
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {

  viewAddPublication: boolean;
  publications: PublicationModel[] = [];
  countLikePub:   number;
  addPublication: any;

  constructor(
    private storage: Storage,
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private pubService: PublicationService) {
      this.publications = new Array<PublicationModel>();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.publications = [];

    this.pubService.data.subscribe((data) => {
      if (data != null) {
        console.log(data);

        this.setData(data);
      }
    }
    );
    this.viewAddPublication = false;
    this.countLikePub = 0;

    this.storage.get('publications').then((val) => {
      this.publications = val;
    });

  }

  setData(data) {
    this.publications.push(data);
  }

  goToAddPub() {
    this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/add-publication', {
      animated: true,
      animationDirection: "forward",

    });
  }

  public likedPost(event) {
    console.log();
    let like = (document.getElementById(event.target.id) as HTMLElement);
    like.style.color = '#0277bd';
    this.countLikePub++;
  }
```

debug mode in chrome

[image]

I need a way to push an array in real time and this is the only way I could think of, the other is to use Socket.io

Comment: What does console.log(data) displays?

Comment: This looks correct to me, can you paste in your entire component?

Comment: I think we need to see more of your HomePage component. It looks correct the way you have written it.

Comment: Check where `publications` is used elsewhere in your component, you may have re-initialized it with something `null` somewhere else in your component.

Comment: @Juance, take account the problem is in a function called `setData` in tab1.page.ts, line 48, not in the code you show us

Comment: @Mridul console.log(data) shows the data being sent.

Comment: @Eliseo 
change that at the last moment, I removed the function and did the logic directly in the subscribe, setData does the same, push on the array

Comment: @John I have edited the post with more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe you are setting publications to `null` because of this function:

```
this.storage.get('publications').then((val) => {
  this.publications = val;
});
```

You could change it a little bit to make sure publications are still an array

```
this.storage.get('publications').then((val) => {
   this.publications = val || [];
});
```

I added `this.publications = val || [];` which is creating an empty array if `val` is not defined

Comment: oh my god I'm dumb thank you so much !! problem solved

Comment: It is difficult to spot even the simplest mistakes. I have done it, and I am pretty sure everyone else has done it too :P I am happy that I could be of help